# Basic C pointer and pass by reference confusion

Tags: c

I have following basic program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(char *c) {
    c = "world";
}

int main() {
    char *c = "hello";
    doit(c);
    printf("%s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Going line by line:

- c stores address to the string (char sequence) it points to
- *c points to "hello" within main function

Now when c (pointer) is passed to the function which tries to modify it. The modified value is not available within main. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(char **c) {
    *c = "world";
}

int main() {
    char *c = "hello";
    doit(&c);
    printf("%s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

works just fine? I am expecting first example to work fine by itself since I am passing `doit(c)` which is already a pointer to string I want to modify.

Comment: Because in the first example you are modifying the copy of the pointer itself, not the memory it points to.

Comment: This is `C` not `C++`. I have removed the `C++` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because in the first version you pass the pointer *by value*. That means the actual pointer from `main` is *copied* and in the `doit` function you only modify the copy.

In the second version you *emulate* pass by reference (C doesn't have proper references) by passing a pointer to the pointer.

---

Lets see if this makes it clearer for you.

For the first program, in the `main` function you have a pointer `c` that points to the string literal `"hello"`:

```
+--------+       +---------+
| main:c | ----> | "hello" |
+--------+       +---------+
```

Then when you pass it to the function, the pointer is copied, so you have this:

```
+--------+
| main:c | --
+--------+   \     +---------+
              >--> | "hello" |
+--------+   /     +---------+
| doit:c | --
+--------+
```

After you change the pointer in `doit` you have this:

```
+--------+       +---------+
| main:c | ----> | "hello" |
+--------+       +---------+

+--------+       +---------+
| doit:c | ----> | "world" |
+--------+       +---------+
```

---

For the second program it start out the same:

```
+--------+       +---------+
| main:c | ----> | "hello" |
+--------+       +---------+
```

But then it changes when you call using a pointer to the pointer:

```
+--------+       +--------+       +---------+
| doit:c | ----> | main:c | ----> | "hello" |
+--------+       +--------+       +---------+
```

Then dereferencing `c` in `doit` gives you the *original* `c` pointer from `main`, and changing it you have

```
+--------+       +--------+       +---------+
| doit:c | ----> | main:c | ----> | "world" |
+--------+       +--------+       +---------+
```

Comment: I understand that `c` is passed by value in first example, however my understanding is that `c` ultimately points to something and if address it stores can be changed with `doit`, `c` will change within main func too.

Example, tracing via gdb within `doit`, `c` lands as a pointer pointing to some address 0x.... , if this is updated directly within `doit`, why won't it reflect within main context?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Updated my answer with some "graphics" to help epxlain the situation.

Comment: Thanks, make a lot of sense now. I now realize that it is always passing by value, even when one is passing pointers they are just passed by value i.e. pointer copied and available on the other side. Would you mind expanding upon "C doesn't have proper references"?

Answer (score 3):

In first case:-

```
void doit(char *c)
```

you are passing pointer by value. And as we know that passing something by value to function means that function can't change original value passed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are passing a copy of **the pointer** `c` to `doit`. As a result whatever modifications you do to the pointer, they will not be reflected in the caller. You change the location where **the copy** of `c` is pointing, but the original `c` remains unchanged.

As a contrast in the second example you pass a **pointer** to the pointer and when you change the value it points to, you change the original pointer `c`.